Redpanda Connect refusing redis connection
I am using Redpanda Connect (formerly known as Benthos) for data streaming and manipulation. I am trying to output the results of my data streaming to a redis stream. I was previously able to do this, but since the switch to Redpanda I have not been able to connect to Redis even though I have a redis server running locally.
Here is the output mapping I have set up for it:
output:
  redis_streams:
    url: tcp://redis:6379
    stream: "newstream" 
    body_key: body
    max_length: 0
    max_in_flight: 64
    metadata:
      exclude_prefixes: []
    batching:
      count: 0
      byte_size: 0
      period: ""
      check: ""

Here is the error I get:
configuration file read error: parseLogs.yaml: (33,1) unable to infer output type from candidates: [redis_streams]
I am not sure if there is something I am missing now but I have not been able to find anything in the docs thus far.
https://docs.redpanda.com/redpanda-connect/components/outputs/redis_streams/?tab=tabs-1-common

Hey @user22884049, are you running a custom build? If yes, please have a look at the updated imports here https://github.com/redpanda-data/redpanda-connect-plugin-example/blob/d1461319dd7f4179bf9095c2cc7b25e8e87239e3/main.go#L8-L13 which show you how to pull the connectors from the Connect repository.
